# how to save a float to nsnumber with just two decimals

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to save a float to an nsnumber but i just want to save it with two decimal places. I know I can do it by converting to an `NSString` first using this code

```
NSString* formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", myFloat];
```

but seems clumsy. All I want to do is convert

```
float numb = 23.25454 into NSNumber 23.25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
float numb = 23.25454;

NSNumber *num = @((int)(numb*100)/100.0);
```

Comment: easy and it works. thanks. is this more efficient than converting to an nsstring then converting to nsnumber?

Comment: Here you have only one conversion - making NSNumber with float via @. In your OP you make string from float, then float from string, and finally NSNumber from float

Comment: Working with primitives is much more efficient than using nsstring formatter

Answer (score 1):

Just round it using any of these functions

```
float rounded = round(val * 100) / 100;
float rounded_down = floorf(val * 100) / 100;
float nearest = floorf(val * 100 + 0.5) / 100;
float rounded_up = ceilf(val * 100) / 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an object oriented approach, try using `NSDecimalNumber` which is a subclass of `NSNumber`. Init the NSDecimalNumber with your float value and then call `decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:`. This gives you a few options of how the truncation or rounding occurs with `NSDecimalNumberBehaviors`, where you can set the scale (number of digits following the decimal) and an NSRoundingMode. Check [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdecimalnumber_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDecimalNumber/decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior%3a) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

It is *impossible* to do this with `float`, `double`, or either of those wrapped as an `NSNumber`. You need to understand how floating point works.

All these use *binary* numbers, you wish to represent a number with exactly two *decimal* places. A binary fraction is made up from a sum of 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16... while a decimal fraction is a sum of 1/10, 1/100, 1/1000... Not all values which can be represented as a sum of values in one of this series can be represented as a sum in the other. This is a similar issue to representing 1/3 in decimal, it is 3/10 + 3/100 + 3/1000 + .....

Try writing, for example, 0.17 = 17/100 = 1/10 + 7/100 as a sum of 1/2, 1/4 etc. Well it's 1/8 + 9/200 = 1/8 + 1/32 + 11/8000 (I'm just doing this on the fly, excuse any errors!) = you figure it out!

To address this there is [the `NSDecimalNumber` class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdecimalnumber_class/reference/reference.html), which is a subclass of `NSNumber` and represents numbers in base-10. The class provides the basic operations to do base-10 arithmetic. You can't mix arithmetic easily between base-10 and base-2 numbers, you cannot even create an `NSDecimalNumber` directly from a `float` or `double` - you format the later as an `NSString` (i.e. convert them to a base-10 representation) - and extracting a `double` value with the `doubleValue` method is described as:

> The approximate value of the receiver as a `double`.

Note the *approximate*.

So a long answer to get to a question: do you really want to *store* a `float` or `double` value to *exactly* two decimal places?

You can use the `round`, `floor` & `ceil` families to do it approximately, but be prepared for results that are "wrong". E.g. try:

```
float a = 371371.28127;
float b = roundf(a * 100.0) / 100.0;
NSLog(@"a: %f | b: %f", a, b);
```

HTH

Comment: helpful. thanks. the example you provided did not produce two decimal places, though.  both a and b values look the same in the log statement.

Comment: @vboombatz - that's the point, using `roundf`, or similar including casting to `int` to truncate, followed by division does not guarantee two decimal places due to the binary vs. decimal representation issues.

Answer (score 1):

NSDecimalNumber with NSDecimalNumberHandler is the best way to get accurate precisions if you want as Object. Below is the sample code.

```
-(NSDecimalNumber *)getRoundedNumberAfterPointDigitsCount:(int)digitsCount withDouble:(double)doubleValue{
    NSDecimalNumber *decimalNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",doubleValue]];
    NSDecimalNumberHandler *decimalHandler = [[NSDecimalNumberHandler alloc] initWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain scale:digitsCount raiseOnExactness:NO raiseOnOverflow:NO raiseOnUnderflow:NO raiseOnDivideByZero:NO];
    decimalNumber =  [decimalNumber decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:decimalHandler];
    return decimalNumber;
}
```

There is more of Rounding option available with NSRoundingMode.

Answer (score 0):

```
float numb = 23.25454;
float myFloat = roundf(100 * numb) / 100.0;
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:myFloat];
```